# Is there a way to comment out a part of a string in c#?

Tags: c#, string, comments

I got this code part here:

```
label1.Text = $"Score: {score} | Speed: {speed}";
```

This shows a score and speed of a breakout game I made. Now I don't need the speed and I wondered if there is a way of commenting out a part of a string.

Of course I could do

```
label1.Text = $"Score: {score}";// | Speed: {speed};
```

but maybe there is another way, so the comment can be removed easier. Something like

```
label1.Text = $"Score: {score} #comment | Speed: {speed} #endcomment";
```

or

```
label1.Text = $"Score: {score} #/*| Speed: {speed} #*/";
```

so it's easier to read and change

Comment: Anything between quotes is part of a string. Comments goes outside

Comment: Can you give a little bit more info about your issue? Since you are the one who setting the value of the string, why removing the unnecessary  parts from the string is unaccaptable? If you want to do some conditional setting, you can use inline conditions by using "?" character. If it is what you are looking for, let me know and I will post an answer for you.

Comment: I still need the „speed“-value, just for debugging, i wanted to remove it from the string. But I didn‘t want to delete it, just commenting out. So I wondered if I could do that in the string itself, rather than excluding it in that comment

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. The question "Is it possible to place a comment inside a string" is not that bad. I mean, you can place variables inside strings, why not comments too?

Comment: I also added a online demo

Comment: If you want to keep it for debugging, only: why not use `#if DEBUG ... string with speed... #else ... string without speed ... #endif`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of commenting out, you can make use of [preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if):

```
#if DEBUG
    label1.Text = $"Score: {score} | Speed: {speed}";
#else
    label1.Text = $"Score: {score}";
#endif
```

DEBUG should be defined when in Debug Mode. That is default in Visual Studio. So you don't need to always comment in and out and keep it in mind to not let it slip into Release output.

Mind that you shouldn't use this excessively. Having many of those will clutter your code and make it unreadable (and a maintainance hell) in the long run. For a specific and small usage like here, it should be fine, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can have your string define on two line like this:

```
label1.Text = $"Score: {score}";
label1.Text += $" | Speed: {speed}";
```

So you can comment it like that:

```
label1.Text = $"Score: {score}";
//label1.Text += $" | Speed: {speed}";
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a method that filters and returns only the ones you need:

```
public static string Filter(string input, params string[] items)
{
  return string.Join("|",input.Split('|').Where(x => items.Contains(x.Split(':')[0].Trim()))); 
}
```

Now You can get it like:

```
string text = $"Score: {score} | Speed: {speed}";

Label1.Text = Filter(text, "Score");
```

Or

```
Label1.Text = Filter(text, "Speed");
```

Or

```
Label1.Text = Filter(text, "Score", "Speed");
```

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u4hgrU)